# How to route log statements to specific file with log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have a `log4j2` appender to log any web and xml content to a specific file, by using a `Marker`.

```
<Appenders>
       <RollingRandomAccessFile name="WEB" fileName="web.log">
        <Filters>
            <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="WEB" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
        </Filters>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
</Appenders>
```

I can successfully use it in my code as follows:

```
logger.info(MarkerFactory.getMarker("WEB"), "myinfo");
```

Additionally I want the content to be printed to sysout console:

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
       <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
    </Console>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="WEB" .../>
 </Appenders>

 <Loggers>
    <Root level="all">
        <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
        <AppenderRef ref="WEB" />
    </Root>
 </Loggers>
```

BUT: Now the following class should be logged in `DEBUG` mode, but only to the `web.log` file, and also be visible in console.

```
<Loggers>
        <logger name="org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter"
                 level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="WEB" />
        </logger>
</Loggers>
```

Result: there are 2 problems:

1) The Filter content is printed to the file, but NOT to `CONSOLE`. I want to log to both.

2) Any normal info loggings that are logged without any Marker (like `logger.info("test")`) are also logged to the WEB.log file. I'd like to prevent this.

Where is my misconfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

1. No marker specified -> log to console
2. Web marker specified -> log to web
3. Filter logger used -> log to web and console

You can achieve this by having three loggers. Set your root logger to only append to console `<AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />`. Set your filter logger to append to both (`<AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />` and `<AppenderRef ref="WEB" />`). Create a third logger with the desired level, and have it append only to web.log by `<AppenderRef ref="WEB" />`. (actually the last step may not even be necessary, if you're specifying the marker; as far as I know, specifying the marker WEB will tell it to only log to web)

Comment: I want to log the WEB-marker statements only to the web.log. But I want to log the `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` output to both console + WEB marker.

Comment: Thanks, regarding point 2: I don't want to *root logger* to log always to WEB. I only want the CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logging to WEB. All other root logging should be untouched.

Comment: what if you have no web-marker? should that just log to console?

Comment: Yes, that should just log to console.

Comment: changed my post again